# Matplotlib/Wxpython: Tooltips on hover/click with multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, tooltip, subplot

I have a matplotlib figure with two subplots (2x1 grid), and I would like to implement tooltips on **one of the two figures**. A lot of the links/examples I see online fall apart when I modify them to have multiple subplots, the tooltip either doesn't appear at all, appears intermittently or the same behaviour occurs on both subplots. I suspect part of the reason is that they always do:

```
self.tooltip = wx.ToolTip(tip='tip test')
self.figure.canvas.SetToolTip(self.tooltip)
```

But this initializes the tooltip across the entire canvas, how can I ensure that the tooltips work as I want only on one of the subplots?

I'm currently doing the following:

```
    self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick3)

    def onpick3(self, event):
        x = event.mouseevent.xdata
        y = event.mouseevent.ydata
        print "x: ", x
        print "y: ", y
```

This just results in console output, not a tooltip.

Comment: I have same question, hoping someone comes along to help..